# emacs gdb does not show the current program cursor in source code buffer

Tags: c++, emacs, gdb

I think when gdb-many-window is on, the primary source code buffer should show where the current program cursor is by an arrow
  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/GDB-User-Interface-Layout.html

But in my case, it is only the gdb buffer that shows where the code is.
The primary source code buffer does not show anything.

Does anyone happen to have the same issue?

Comment: I found why. I have to use gdb --fullname

Comment: If you found the solution, feel free to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Having real answers instead of just comments improves the quality of our content.

Answer (score 0):

I found why. I have to use 
   gdb --fullname
This is emacs 2.24. Although I do not know why this flag is important.